# Not getting the desired output. Can someone tell me the solution?

Tags: c, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

int calsum(int x, int y, int z);

void main()
{
    int a,b,c,i, sum;
    for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        printf("\n Enter Number %d\n", i);

    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    sum= calsum(a,b,c);
    printf("\nSum=%d", sum);
}

int calsum(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int d;
    d = x + y + z;
    return (d);
}
```

Hi, I want to enter the numbers one by one but the output I'm getting is..

```
amol@amol-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC ~/Desktop/C codes $ ./a.out

Enter Number 1

Enter Number 2

Enter Number 3
```

Whereas i want it to ask me for the input one at a time. Please help me. I'm new to this.

Comment: Real question is  more about taking input than the output .

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays for that

```
int a[3], i, sum;
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
{
    printf("\n Enter Number %d\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
sum = calsum(a[0], a[1], a[2]);
```

Comment: what about the rest of the code? ie what changes should i make to the other functions?

Comment: Paul Ogilvie, what should i do in the calsum function?

Comment: can you help me with the changes in need to make in the functions? @haris

Comment: @AmolSehgal Your function is fine  , you don't need to make any change to that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `for` loop only has one line of code inside of it,

   ```
   printf("\n Enter Number %d\n", i);
   ```

   so the output is correct.
2. The `main()` must return `int`.
3. You **must** check the return value of `scanf()`.
4. You can use something like this

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int calsum(int x, int y, int z);
   int getinteger();

   int main()
   {
       int a, b, c, z;

       a = getinteger(1);
       b = getinteger(2);
       c = getinteger(3);

       z = calsum(a, b, c);

       printf("\nSum = %d", z);

       return 0;
   }

   int calsum(int x, int y, int z)
   {
       int d;
       d = x + y  +z;
       return d;
   }

   int getinteger(int index)
   {
       int value;
       printf("Enter the %dth number > ", index);
       while (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
       {
           int chr;
           while (((chr = getchar()) != '\n') && (chr != EOF))
               continue;
           printf("Invalid input -- try again\n");
           printf("Enter the %dth number > ", index);
       }
       return value;
   }
   ```